# getJson doesn't call action on Controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2

trying do a cascade update in a dropDownList, but the $.getJson wasn't call the action on Controller. I'm using mvc 2 and SqlServer 2008 with Entitie

Please could you give me some direction to follow. Thanks in advance.

Controller AdminProduto

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult PegarSubCategoriaProduto(int categoria)
        {
            IQueryable<SubCatProduto> subCatProduto = repository.ListarSubCategoriasDeProdutoPorCategoria(categoria);
            SelectList subCategoria = new SelectList(subCatProduto, "sub_cat_produto_id", "sub_cat_produto_nome");

            return Json(subCategoria, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

SiteAdmin.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>Administração Tudo de Massinha</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="logindisplay">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
            </div> 

            <div id="menucontainer">

                <ul id="menu">                      
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Vídeo", "Index", "AdminVideo")%></li>            
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Produto", "Index", "AdminProduto")%></li>
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Categoria Produto", "Index", "AdminCatProduto")%></li>
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("SubCategoria Produto", "Index", "AdminSubCatProduto")%></li>
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Galeria", "Index", "AdminGaleria")%></li>
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Categoria Galeria", "Index", "AdminCatGaleria")%></li>
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("SubCategoria Galeria", "Index", "AdminSubCatGaleria")%></li>                    
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page Novo.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/SiteAdmin.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TudoDeMassinha.ViewModel.ProdutoViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    TUDO DE MASSINHA - Admin - Novo Produto
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


    <h2>Produto</h2>
    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Novo", "AdminProduto", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){%>
         <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Por favor corrija os erros abaixo e tente novamente:")%>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Novo Produto</legend>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Detalhes</legend>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_id)%>
                    </div>          
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Produto.produto_id, new { disabled = "disabled" })%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_id)%>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.cat_produto_id)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%:Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Produto.cat_produto_id, Model.Categoria,"-- Selecione uma Categoria -- ")%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.cat_produto_id)%>
                    </div>            
                </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.sub_cat_produto_id)%>
                    </div>
                    <%--<div class="editor-field">--%>
                        <%--<%:Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Produto.sub_cat_produto_id, Model.SubCategoria, "-- Selecione uma Sub Categoria --")%>--%>
                        <select id="subCat" name="subCat" disabled="disabled"></select>
                        <%--<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.sub_cat_produto_id)%>--%>
                    <%--</div>   --%>         
                </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_nome)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Produto.produto_nome)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_nome)%>
                    </div>            
                </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_descricao)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Produto.produto_descricao)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_descricao)%>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_preco)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Produto.produto_preco)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_preco)%>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_quantidade)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Produto.produto_quantidade)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_quantidade)%>
                    </div>
               </div>               

                <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_peso)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Produto.produto_peso)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_peso)%>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_altura)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Produto.produto_altura)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_altura)%>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_largura)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Produto.produto_largura)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_largura)%>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_comprimento)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Produto.produto_comprimento)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_comprimento)%>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <%--<div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_data_inicio)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Produto.produto_data_inicio)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_data_inicio)%>                    
                    </div>
               </div>--%>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_promocao)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        Sim <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Produto.produto_promocao, 1)%>
                        Não <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Produto.produto_promocao, 0)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_promocao)%>
                    </div>
               </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.produto_ativo)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        Sim <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Produto.produto_ativo, 1)%>
                        Não <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Produto.produto_ativo, 0)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.produto_ativo)%>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </fieldset>
            <%--<fieldset>
                <legend>Vídeos</legend>
                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Video.produto_video_nome)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Video.produto_video_nome)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Video.produto_video_nome)%>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="caixa-detalhe">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Video.produto_video_url)%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Video.produto_video_url)%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Video.produto_video_url)%>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>--%>

           <fieldset>
            <legend>Imagem 1</legend>
                <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        Icone 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                         <input type="file" name="icone1" id="icone1" />               
                    </div>               
                    <div id="previa_imagem">
                       <!--Colocar ajax para previa da imagem que será incluida --> 
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                <div class="editor-label">
                    Imagem 1
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                     <input type="file" name="imagem1" id="imagem1"  />    
                </div>               
                <div class="previa_imagem">
                   <!--Colocar ajax para previa da imagem que será incluida --> 
                </div>
            </div>
           </fieldset>

          <fieldset>
            <legend>Imagem 2</legend>
                <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                <div class="editor-label">
                    Icone 2
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                     <input type="file" name="icone2" id="icone2" />               
                </div>               
                <div class="previa_imagem">
                   <!--Colocar ajax para previa da imagem que será incluida --> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                <div class="editor-label">
                    Imagem 2
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                     <input type="file" name="imagem2" id="imagem2" />    
                </div>               
                <div class="previa_imagem">
                   <!--Colocar ajax para previa da imagem que será incluida --> 
                </div>
            </div>
           </fieldset>
           <fieldset>
            <legend>Imagem 3</legend>
                <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                <div class="editor-label">
                    Icone 3
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                     <input type="file" name="icone3" id="icone3" />               
                </div>               
                <div class="previa_imagem">
                   <!--Colocar ajax para previa da imagem que será incluida --> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                <div class="editor-label">
                    Imagem 3
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                     <input type="file" name="imagem3" id="imagem3" />    
                </div>               
                <div class="previa_imagem">
                   <!--Colocar ajax para previa da imagem que será incluida --> 
                </div>
            </div>
           </fieldset>
           <fieldset>
            <legend>Imagem 4</legend>
                <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                <div class="editor-label">
                    Icone 4
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                     <input type="file" name="icone4" id="icone4" />               
                </div>               
                <div class="previa_imagem">
                   <!--Colocar ajax para previa da imagem que será incluida --> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="caixa-detalhe"> 
                <div class="editor-label">
                    Imagem 4
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                     <input type="file" name="imagem4" id="imagem4" />    
                </div>               
                <div class="previa_imagem">
                   <!--Colocar ajax para previa da imagem que será incluida --> 
                </div>
            </div>
           </fieldset>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#Produto_cat_produto_id").change(function () {

            var categoriaId = $(this).val();
            var subCategoria = $("#subCat");


            if (categoriaId.length > 0) {
                subCategoria.attr("disabled", false);
                ajustarSubCategoriaDropDown();
            } else {
                subCategoria.attr("disabled", true);
                subCategoria.emptySelect();                
            }
        });


        function ajustarSubCategoriaDropDown() {

            var categoriaId = $("#Produto_cat_produto_id").val();
            var subCategoria = $("#subCat");
            if (categoriaId.length > 0) {
                //working until here
                $.getJSON('/AdminProduto/PegarSubCategoriaProduto/', {categoria : categoriaId },
        function (data) {
            alert("worked");
        });

            }
}


</script>
    <div class="voltar-link">
        <a href="<%: Url.Action("Index") %>">
            <img src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Img/Design/voltar.png") %>" alt="Voltar" title="Voltar para Lista"/>
        </a>
    </div>    

</asp:Content>
```

This part works until the comment "work until here"

```
       $("#Produto_cat_produto_id").change(function () {

            var categoriaId = $(this).val();
            var subCategoria = $("#subCat");


            if (categoriaId.length > 0) {
                subCategoria.attr("disabled", false);
                ajustarSubCategoriaDropDown();
            } else {
                subCategoria.attr("disabled", true);
                subCategoria.emptySelect();                
            }
        });


        function ajustarSubCategoriaDropDown() {

            var categoriaId = $("#Produto_cat_produto_id").val();
            var subCategoria = $("#subCat");
            if (categoriaId.length > 0) {
                //working until here
                $.getJSON('/AdminProduto/PegarSubCategoriaProduto/', {categoria : categoriaId },
        function (data) {
            alert("worked");
        });

            }
}
```

Comment: Hi, guys any Idea, the problem is the call on JavaScript wasn't call the Action on Controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) uses a GET request and your controller action is decorated with `[HttpPost]`, so will not allow GET requests (only POST).

To get it working, you can either:

1. Change your action to allow GET (decorate with `[HttpGet]` instead of `[HttpPost]`)

   or:
2. Switch to using [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) in your jQuery call.

Comment: Nice. Works in both ways. Thanks a lot.